# How to digitally sign .bin format POSIX shell script executable

Tags: linux, code-signing, sign, bin

I have created a linux installer **.bin** format  using installanywhere but we couldn't sign using digital signing certificate, can anyone guide how to sign it?

I got following message when I sign with jarsigner: `invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error`

Comment: What do you mean by you "couldn't" sign? What problems do you face? Any errors?

Comment: I got following message when i sign with jarsigner.

** invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error **

Comment: The message is obvious. The executable file format is not recognized. Linux expects executable files to be of ELF file format. If your bin file was created on Windows (PE file format), it won't work on Linux.